# Parallel For-Loop in R reading Variables From CSV

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm trying to optimize a computationally expensive analysis by parallelizing the for-loop I'm using. The script I've attempted is as follows:

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv")
var1 <- data$Var1
var2 <- data$Var2

d <- foreach(i = 2:7,
     .packages = c("gRain", "bnlearn")
) %dopar% {
  for (x in var1) {
    for (y in var2) {
      exposed = querygrain(setEvidence(database, nodes = c(x),
                states = c("1"), propagate = T),
            nodes = y)[[1]][2]
      unexposed = querygrain(setEvidence(database, nodes = c(x),
                states = c("0"), propagate = T),
            nodes = y)[[1]][2]
      
      x
      y
      exposed/unexposed
  }
 }
}
print(d)
```

Basically, I'm trying to parallelize comparing probabilities between two variables stored in a CSV file from rows 2 to 7.
My output currently looks like this:

[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL

[[6]]
NULL

I've tried a few different tutorials using 'foreach', but each one I'm finding is just generating data in-code, so it's not helping my problem.

I should also add that this 6 variable dataset is just a test set; the actual dataset is much larger.

I'm completely self-taught, so I'm sure I'm just missing something simple somewhere. I appreciate any help anyone might offer

EDIT:
The non-parallel version of the for-loop runs fine and is as follows:

```
###Import previously constructed Bayesian Network 
database = import("bayesnet.RData")

data <- read.csv("data.csv") 
var1 <- data$Var1 
var2 <- data$Var2

for (x in var1) {
    for (y in var2) {
      exposed = querygrain(setEvidence(database, nodes = c(x),
                states = c("1"), propagate = T),
            nodes = y)[[1]][2]
      unexposed = querygrain(setEvidence(database, nodes = c(x),
                states = c("0"), propagate = T),
            nodes = y)[[1]][2]
  
      x
      y
      exposed/unexposed  
 } 
}
```

I apologize for not noting that 'database' is a prebuilt Bayesian Net analysis that I have previously read in as a .RData object and should not be part of the problem, but I've included the importation of this object in the edit.

"data.csv" is simply a metadata file that contains a list of variables I need to compare in a pair-wise manner. The non-parallel loop works fine with it. The issue is that the 'full' dataset is an 86x86 matrix that takes roughly 2 hrs to fully run. I'm just trying to optimize this a little to make the analysis faster as our variable set grows.

Comment: It seems very suspect that you aren't use `i` inside the `%dopar%{}` part of the loop. Also you create `data` before the loop but use `database` inside the loop - are those supposed to be the same?

Comment: It might help if you shared a working, non-parallel version of the code you want to run. Because it seems like your parallelization attempt has more issues than just the parallelization.

Comment: I've updated the question to address your comments. In terms of using `i` inside `%dopar%{}`, that is because I'm attempting to replicate the best fitting tutorials I can find, each of which use `i` inside `foreach()`.

Comment: Regarding `i`, you should certainly use `i` (or some variable) inside `foreach()`, but then if you don't **also** use it inside the `%dopar%{}` then each iteration is identical. They way you've wrapped your working code in `%dopar%{}` will attempt to run your existing loops 6 times.

Comment: Instead, your `foreach` should replace the outer `for()` in your code, though it would also need some modification so the results are collected in the inner loop and returned in the outer loop, before being combined by `foreach`. It's hard though for us to test/debug without access to a reproducible example with sample data...

Comment: I appreciate your comments, and I'll do some experimenting. I would provide example data if I could, but this analysis is dependent on the Bayesian Network, which I am not able to share.